# Create slideshow from text

Tags: api, openoffice.org, openoffice-impress

I would like to read text from **3 text paragraphs** & use the text to **create a slideshow** of 3 slides - each with a paragraph programatically.

**Is it possible?** Do I need to use openoffice, libreoffice or something else?

I have googled a lot, but could not find any answer. Hence, posting the question on SO.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Openoffice has a bridge called [Uno](http://udk.openoffice.org/) which can be used from python, java (and probably more), i.e. you can manipulate openoffice documents from an external program, it's however non-trivial to use it.

Another possibility is to use [OpenOffice.org BASIC](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide).